# Show whole FTP directory

Tags: .net, ftp, directory, hidden, chilkat

My application don't finde some files in FTP Directorys.

I checked the folder with the FTP Client WinSCP which shows me every file. The files and folders, which are hidden, starts with a dot `.`.

I'm using Chilkat for FTP Connection, but tried the same with standard .NET functions. They are returning that the folder is empty.

WinSCP shows:

[image: WinSCP]

My Application shows:

[image: My Application]

What's the right way to show everything?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Not sure if this can help you: http://www.chilkatforum.com/questions/1414/best-way-to-view-hidden-files-via-ftp

Comment: If that solved or helped to solve your problem, why don't you post the solution as an aswer here?. It could be of help for future readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Steve's help i solved it.

I have set the Chilkat FTP ListPattern property to "-a" and every file is shown now.

(This only works with Unix-based systems)

Thanks Steve